# download webkit sources automaticly

Tags: linux, download, webkit

i need to create a program that downloads the source code for all versions of 
webkit. and i need to do it in linux.
the problem is that i cant find an ftp address where i can download it.
when looking in the page - [The WebKit Open Source Project](http://www.webkit.org/building/checkout.html)
there is only an option for windows and mac OS.
or for browsing the code online.
i want to be able to create a directory in my local computer inside that directory i will have a directory for each version source code.

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Taking a look at it, it's got a publicly available Subversion repository.  Install Subversion if you don't already have it, and use the command-line instructions.

If you're going to use Open Source on the Internet, you really should be familiar enough with Subversion, Git, Mercurial, and possibly other VCSs to get code checked out from them.

Also, I found [what looks like nightly build tarballs](http://nightly.webkit.org/) on the site.  They may be more useful.

Comment: you are right , but i want to create a script that will work on every system even if they dont have subversion installed.

Comment: If they don't have subversion installed then you can't use those instructions, period.

Answer (score 2):

Those are specific procedures for OS X and Windows; Linux users don't need to follow them, just the other parts.

Comment: so you say i need to follow all instructions outside the windows and mac OS boxes ?